# Textsubscript within a threeparttable

Tags: subscripts, threeparttable

I need some text in a subscript within a threeparttable. It seems like all possible ways to achieve subscript, do this by creating a math environment. Which I understand the threeparttable does not allow? Any suggestions? Thanx :-)

Comment: Can you make a short example of the subscript you need to get?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using sub- and superscripts within a threeparttable without any problems, using `\textsubscript{"text"}` A simple example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
alpha\textsubscript{a} & beta\textsubscript{b} & gamma\textsubscript{c} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

It then gives this:

[image: simple table with subscript]

Fingers crossed that helps!

Comment: it didn't. BUT entering math mode did work! $_S$ (I just needed the S) Thank you for your time anyways!

Comment: @Nora maybe your LaTeX is outdated. In earlier versions one needed to load the `fixltx2e` package for using `\textsubscript`.